# Illustrator plug-in to create artboards from Excel file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, plugin, import, microsoft-excel

I am searching for Adobe Illustrator plug-in that can read data from a MS Excel file and create many artboards with text data from that file (one artboard per table row). Also it would be cool if I could specify a background pattern and text placeholders for all artboards, so text from Excel file will be put instead of those placeholders, above the given pattern.

Does such plug-in exist?

Comment: The builtin functionality does not work for you?

Comment: @joojaa Oh, didn't know this can be done with builtin functionality. Could you please give me a friendly hint where to search or what to google?

Comment: @Silly-V Thank you so much, that worked, you're awesome!

Comment: @Silly-V Please turn that into an answer. Please avoid answering questions in the comments. Beyond not netting you rep, it also disables the OP from checking your answer as accepted. Which is bad for site stats. Lastly, comments are meant as temporary and could be deleted later. Answers won't. Thanks!

Comment: Reps, popularity or superficial titles are meaningless to me... I live for the craft, I live for ART! ...but as you say sir, I do apologize sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with built-in Illustrator functionality, that is described in details in [this video](http://youtu.be/eCBrK8tZAXQ).

Have checked, it works.

Comment: Hello vortexxx192. Could you please give the gist of the technique displayed in the video? That way, your answer is still of value when the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is rampant, and we are very weary of link-only answers because of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script to import data from csv file, but you would have to do some action-engineering when batch-processing the data to do your extra stuff. After data is imported, it's inside the AI document as variable datasets. You batch-process the datasets using the Batch command inside the Actions flyout menu. Then, the fun part is to rig an action to create your artboards. It can be done by pasting a rectangle and converting to artboards. You can also have a max of 100 artboards in a single document. Learn about the script here: http://youtu.be/eCBrK8tZAXQ